# Share laptop Wi-Fi with router set up as access point via ethernet cables

Tags: wireless-networking

I have an ADSL modem which serves as a wireless router. There's a laptop connected to it through cable. On the other room I have a laptop which is connected through the router wirelessly.

Since I have other appliances that need to get connected but are not Wi-Fi capable I have another Wi-Fi router.

How can I share the second laptop's Wi-Fi with the second router so that the router can then serve as an access point to give internet to my other appliances through ethernet cables?

I want something like this:

INTERNET>MODEM (WIFI)>LAPTOP 1 (WIFI)>LAPTOP 2 (WIFI)>Router 2 (ETHERNET)>DREAMBOX & WDTV

What I've tried so far is opened the admin interface of router 2 then set static IP 192.168.100.13 and disabled the DHCP.  The DHCP of the main router starts with 192.168.100.1 then I hooked up router 2 with the laptop 2 through Cat5 cable but for some reason it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

For best results, run a long ethernet wire from your original router to where your new router will be located. Really. You'll thank yourself later.

When that is done, disable dhcp on your new router and set it up with a static IP address in the same subnet as your original router. You also want to give it the same SSID and security settings as your original wireless network. Connect the wire you ran to a *LAN port* (not the WAN port) on both ends. Congratulations, you new router will now function as an access point, and all of your devices will work on the same network and be able to see each other, and your laptops will be able to freely roam between the two routers without dropping the connection.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) but that's the problem i can't afford to have a cable running across 10m2 it's just too ugly..can't i just share my wifi with router 2 via ethernet?

Comment: There are flat network cables available which even fit under the carpet and also almost "invisible" along the toeboard, see e.g. [this Cat6 patch cable](http://www.amazon.com/Cables-Unlimited-UTP-1800-25W-Patch-White/dp/B0007QQJWA/). so you can hide it, and do not need to microwave your brain :) Moreover, it is probably more reliable and faster than a WiFi connection. That's how I connected my Dreambox etc. via a cheap 4-port ethernet switch (no WiFi).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f31/sharing-wifi-over-ethernet-cable-425331.html

Bridge your two network connections (the WiFi and ethernet) and you can connect the second device with a crossover cable.

Answer (score 0):

If your routers are supported (you didn't say which models you have), you could install 3rd party software on them such as [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) or [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato).  They can open up access to many more capabilities on your routers.

I set up something similar:

- Internet modem wired to Linksys(DD-WRT) wireless router.
- Another Linksys(DD-WRT) modem on the other side of the house was setup as a wireless bridge.

That has the effect of running a cable from a LAN port on one router to a LAN port on the other.  Making sure the second router had DHCP turned off, I basically had a four port switch connected to the gateway router wirelessly.